Regulated Power Supply Problem
My capacitor blew up, and I can't see any problems in my schematic and PCB layout. Our professor said that we need a 2200 µF capacitor (C1) for this project and a 12 V, 1 A transformer. Will this work if I replace the 2200 µF capacitor with a 1000 µF one, and still use the 12V 1A transformer?

I got this picture in Google.
This is my schematic; C2 = 0.1 µF, C4=10 µF, C3=470 µF:

This is my PCB Layout:


So how does it behave? And with the 2200?

@SolarMike the 2200 capacitor blown up when i used that

@MarkchaelIrishVacalares What capacitor it was, how much voltage rating and was the polarity correct? Capacitors do not blow up very often unless used wrong. And whether a 1000uF will work in place does not depend much on the transformer, but what kind of output you need from the regulator (current at some voltage).

Welcome! When did it fail? Startup? No load? Max load? What's your open circuit secondary voltage of your transformer?

You have to attribute the source of this image. "I got this picture in google" isn't enough.

Show us a picture of the assembled board, both sides. It's possible that a stray short or assembly fault caused this problem. Also, what clearance have you used around the 220V nets?

@LordTeddy It looks like OP is using an off-board transformer, which sensibly avoids mains voltage on the PCB

Did you just assemble the C1 with the wrong polarity, then it blows up! Or you used a very old (10 years +) electrolytic capacitor, that was never used? -> can blow up.

Your layout on the PCB is not very good, consider making it similar to the schematic - e. g. C1- is very far away from D1/D4's cathodes. You can use pieces of wires as 0 Ohm resistor. And consider the hints from data sheet LM317 - e g. chapter 11.2. and values for C3 and C4 as proposed there too - I assume Tantal capacitors or even parallel to a ceramic one...

With a 24 V transformator output and C1 1mF and 1A max = good rule of thumb, but  then UC1 average will be roughly 24 VDC, UC1 min is 21 V? So Output voltage from 1.25 ... 18 V will be stable,  all above will be unstable - a DC with added 100 Hz ripple pulses...

The cap is just a bulk cap to counter surges in the supply, so the value won't be critical. The most likely reason it would blow up is some student switching polarity on the connectors, then hooking it up to something without current limit - boom. Try it on a current limited bench supply at first, before trying the 230VAC. Use colored banana connectors or similar, red for 24V, black for 0V.
Or perhaps the part was mounted backwards.
Other remarks:

To prevent further pyrotechnic effects, maybe at the very least design in a poor man's polarity protection such as a series Schottky rated at several Ampere. A TVS just after said Schottky doesn't hurt either.

You've got to realize that LM317 is a heat generator which comes with the side effect of also working as a voltage regulator.
There's just no way you can get a LM317 to deliver 1A at the low voltages mentioned - it will melt through the floor long before that, even if you put on a massive external heat sink. And there's no internal heat sink in your layout, nor is there room for an external one, so this is simply not gonna work - the regulator will probably go into thermal shutdown just with very little load and become unreliable in general.
IMPORTANT Do not place that naked adjust pad heatsink part of the TO220 right next to any other component! Particularly not potentiometers or connectors that one might have a reason to touch with one's fingers. It will get hot up towards some 150°C and stay warm for a while even after you cut the power.
The way to design these old kind of old timer linear regulators is to use several of them in series to split up the heat, like a fixed one down to some 15V or such, then a variable one from there. Getting the whole span of 1.25V to 32V seems overly optimistic. If you just go from 12V to 1.25V that will probably work ok. But always use TO220 heatsinks - it's a thing.

The cap values in the first schematic look ok for input/output but then you picked some other values for whatever reason. Use the values specified in The Friendly Datasheet of the LM317. Also for lower cap values you can use film caps or ceramics rated at some 50V but without the polarity concerns of aluminum electrolytes.


